# Class project - can't understand what I'm doing wring

Tags: java

It is suppose to show in the screen "sorry i cant eat it" if it contains gluten, otherwise it will show something like "okay to eat"

I added the code including all the comments/instructions. I was trying to work on this for a few hours already but can't figure out why it is not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaLab23{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      // first we define our input streams.
      InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);   


            // put declarations here
      String peanutButter, chocolate, gluTen;  
      String cookieName ;
      String containsChocolate, containsPenutbutter;

      // we catch exceptions if some are thrown.
      try {
            //prompt the user for the animals name and read the input
            //the name will be used when prompting for more information
            System.out.println("what is the name of your cookie?");
            cookieName = reader.readLine();

            //prompt the user for the animals color and read the input
            System.out.println("Does  the " + cookieName + " cookie contain chocolate?");
            containsChocolate = reader.readLine();

            //comparing strings can be tricky, using a function 
            //such as compareTo, compareToIgnoreCase will be the best
            // 0 means the two strings are identical
            // <0 sFriendly precedes "yes", and >0 the other way around
           //if (containsChocolate.compareToIgnoreCase("yes")==0)
               System.out.println(" Does  the " + cookieName + " cookie contain peanut butter?");

               //if (containsChocolate.compareToIgnoreCase("yes")==0)
                //System.out.println("Does  the " + cookieName + " cookie contain peanut butter?");
                 //prompt the user for the animals color and read the input
            System.out.println("Does  the " + cookieName + " cookie contain gluten?");
            containsChocolate = reader.readLine();

            if (containsChocolate.compareToIgnoreCase("yes")==0)
                System.out.println(cookieName + "sorry i cant eat it.");


        /**************** TRUTH TABLE **************
          * condition 1 = peanutButter == yes
          * condition 2 = chocolate == yes
          * condition 3 = gluTen == no
          *              
          *  condition1    condition2   condition3      C1 or C2 and C3        (C1 OR C2) AND C3
          *  T             T            t                 T                     T
          *  T             T            F                 T                     F
          *  T             F            T                 T                     T
          *  T             F            F                 T                     F                  
          *  F             T            t                 T                     T
          *  F             T            F                 F                     F
          *  F             F            T                 F                     F
          *  F             F            F                 F                     F
          * 
          *  
          * ********************************************/

        System.out.println("C1: " + (peanutButter == yes) +" C2: "+ (chocolate == yes) + "C3 :" + (gluTen == no));
        System.out.println("C1 OR C2 AND C3" + (peanutButter == yes || chocolate == yes && gluTen == no);
        System.out.println("(C1 OR C2) AND C3" + ((peanutButter == yes || chocolate == yes) && gluTen == no));


      } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error reading from user");
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thats Java, not Javascript.

Comment: That’s not JavaScript, it’s Java. Please edit title and tags to reflect that.

Comment: As it stands, this code won't compile - mainly due to the `(peanutButter == yes)`, etc. at the end. When it did compile, what was wrong? What did it *not* do as expected?

Comment: What are your inputs and what are you expecting exactly + what is going wrong?

Comment: Don't use `==` with `String`, use `equals()`. (assuming you meant `peanutButter == "yes"` etc)

Comment: Additionally, you are assigning the result from your "contains gluten" question to the containsChocolate variable. You are also not using your peanutButter, chocolate, gluTen vars until you are checking conditions at the end. They will all be null and as a result False if you are checking to see if they are equal to yes.

Comment: You should use `boolean` type for true/false (like in your case yes/no) variables. Then you can do checks like `(peanutButter == true)` and you will be able to output them by `System.out.println()` method and use in logical statements like `peanutButter || chocolate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While comparing two String, you should write constant String first as `"yes".compareToIgnoreCase(peanutButter)==0` this will prevent you from NullPointerException. Also objects can not be compared with using "==", String is a java Object and you should use its "equals" method. Try code at the below.

```
if ("yes".compareToIgnoreCase(gluTen)==0)
    System.out.println(cookieName + " sorry i cant eat it.");
else
    System.out.println(cookieName + " okay to eat");



System.out.println("C1: " + ("yes".compareToIgnoreCase(peanutButter)==0) +" C2: "+ ("yes".compareToIgnoreCase(chocolate)==0) + "C3: " + ("no".compareToIgnoreCase(gluTen)==0));
System.out.println("C1 OR C2 AND C3" + ("yes".compareToIgnoreCase(peanutButter)==0 || "yes".compareToIgnoreCase(chocolate)==0 && "no".compareToIgnoreCase(gluTen)==0));
System.out.println("(C1 OR C2) AND C3" + (("yes".compareToIgnoreCase(peanutButter)==0 || "yes".compareToIgnoreCase(chocolate)==0) && "no".compareToIgnoreCase(gluTen)==0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare Strings like (peanutButter.equals("yes")) and not like (peanutButter == yes).